# Baseboard heater install from room to room?

Tags: baseboard, heater

I am looking to install 240v electric baseboard heaters which will be fed with 12-2 on 20 amp breakers. I did my amperage calculation 4000/240v = 16.6 amps. So with that said I can run all my heaters on one 20 amp breaker considering you are allowed 18 amps on a 20 amp breaker per IRC 2009 code.

1st question: However, does anyone know if there is code against feeding from one room to another (piggyback) my feed from the thermostat to the next room.

These heaters will be installed in 2 bedrooms, a bathroom and a walk in closet.

2nd question: Is GFCI circuit breakers required for these heaters? From what I gather from the IRC 2009 Code any equipment ran with 220v does not need GFCI breakers. Or am I wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes you can, you can get a 2 pole GFCI breaker. Although I'm pretty sure you don't need one for this application.

Comment: @Ariel, I didn't say they don't have 2-pole GFCIs, I haven't used or come across one that's strictly 240V only 120/240; I found one though - thanks.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I don't understand your distinction. To get 240V you just have two 120V breakers. You can use this GFCI either as 240V (between hots) or 120V (hot to neutral) and the GFCI function will work correctly.

Comment: @Duane No one answered you. I don't know code well enough to answer you, but from a safety point of view what you describe sounds fine, and you don't need a GFCI. Just make sure your thermostat is rated for the amount of power you are going to put into it.

Comment: One thing that is not clear is if the the four heaters are a total of 4000W or if they are 4000W each. If each heater is 4000W then you will need a separate wired circuit for each heater.

Comment: @Ariel. It's not always that simple; it depends on the manufacturer and the intended use (common trip/single lever). There are 120/240V GFIs and 240V GFIs. [The distinction is the way it monitors current](http://www.nema.org/Products/Documents/NEMA-GFCI-2012-Field-Representative-Presentation.pdf). But, as I eluded to, I've wired *1* 2-pole GFI to a hot tub so you could be right, however I can't see why someone would produce two products that are effectively the same thing.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils You don't need a strictly 240v GFCI, one that also monitors the neutral will work just fine. All 240v household breakers are double pole.

Comment: Thank you all. @Ariel, yes my thermostats are rated for 240v use. 

So from what I read do I need a double pole 20 amp breaker or am I able to just use a single pole 20 amp? Im a bit confused on that. 

I did not clarify that but yes all the heaters combined equal 4000 watts.


Anyone know what kind of wire is ran for carbon monoxide and smoke detectors? They all need wired together and put on an Arc Fault breaker? Ive searched code but it does not come right out and say exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: @Ariel, it's not *my* distinction. Resi wiring guide based on NEC says - Use 120/240 2p breakers on 3-wire circuits (2 hots and a neut.)(ranges/ovens) and 240 2p breakers on "straight 240V" (air conditioners/ **baseboard heaters**). We're talking past one another if you feel you have to tell me 240 breakers are 2p, I said *single-lever* not single-pole. I was explaining where my og. comment came from and saying - only at a high level, or speaking about a specific brand, can you say 240 is just two breakers.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I agree that we're not actually disagreeing. I'm just having a hard time understanding what you are writing, that's all. And for this installation either type of GFCI would work fine, so I did not understand why you called it out - why does it matter? (Not that he needs GFCI anyway.) And [residential] 240v is always 2 breakers. They might both be in the same box, but internally it's two breakers.

Comment: @Duane Thermostat rated for 240v is not enough, they must also be rated for 4kW. You need a double pole for 240V. You can technically combine two separate breakers, but it's best to get a single combo unit. No you do not put smoke detectors on an arc fault breaker! For the detectors I think they just use ordinary 14gauge electrical wire. You get what's called 14/3 - i.e. 14guage, 3 conductors (4 really if you count the ground). You use the red wire to interlink them, and the black/white to provide power.

Comment: @Ariel, Ok thank you. I should have clarified that each thermostat will run only 2 baseboard heaters. So I have a total of 4 thermostat switches. 1 in master bed, 1 in 2nd bedroom, 1 in master bath and 1 in walk in closet. I realized the way I had explained what I had going on it made it sound as if all the baseboard heaters would be on 1 thermostat. With that said I should be fine 2 baseboard heaters per thermostat? These were a friend of ours thermostats. 1 thermostat was hooked to (2) 48" 240v heaters. Thanks for the verification on the smoke alarms!